# Why am I getting the error "MyActivity is not an enclosing class?"

Tags: android, android-intent

I had a libgdx program which starts with the following class:

```
public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler
```

I needed to have an `Activity` class to detect screen size using `Display` (I can't do that in an `AndroidApplication` class).

So I added the following class as my launcher `Activity`:

```
public class MyActivity1 extends Activity
```

So in my new class `MyActivity1` I try to run my old class `MyActivity`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

But I got the following compilation error: **MyActivity is not an enclosing class**

Manifest is as follows

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity1"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"/>
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Why are you calling the same activity from itself?

Comment: No. Main class is MyActivity1 which should run MyActivity

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with this

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity1.this, MyActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
```

The new Intent requires the current activity's context (first param) and the class which you want initializate (second param).

Comment: Ooops! Yes. I misprinted the same classes in "Intent myIntent = new Intent". Thank you!

Comment: @nms You may reconsider your naming conventions. I can see how you could easily mix those up and that makes me think your variable names may be similarly named. This is going to cause you big headaches in the future as you can see. You will be better off if you try making them a little more meaningful to their responsibilities

Comment: I was making the same mistake when I copy pasted that intent line in a rush :s