# Android - How to inflate an activity layout to fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Hi I am still beginner in android programming. I have made tablayout in my program and when I click the tab I'd like the fragment to display the activity layout.

The purpose is for the widget inside the activity such as button' and recycler view'functions can be done.

I've tried to inflate activity layout it displayed exactly what I want however when I click a button inside, the application stop working instead of toast that what i have set.

Is there any other method? Please help me

Here is the logcat:

```
05-27 12:43:41.720 12549-12549/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen, PID: 12549
                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickLogin(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnLogin'
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the java class for fragment

```
public class FragmentFriends extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login,container,false);
}
}
```

Below is the xml file of activity_login

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen.LoginActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPswd"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:onClick="clickLogin"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

public void clickLogin(View view){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: show logcat on crash

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have added the logcat

Comment: Post your code snippets @NatJ. So that the community can provide you with more accurate answers. :)

Comment: @McAwesomville I just add that

Comment: is your problem solved ?@NatJ

Comment: For the button yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `clickLogin()` attribute from **xml** file.

OR

create method `clickLogin(View view)` in fragment,

```
public void clickLogin(View view) {

}
```

**replace**

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: what is issue now ?@NatJ

Comment: LoginActivity is not an enclosing class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443646/why-am-i-getting-the-error-myactivity-is-not-an-enclosing-class

Comment: I have read the link and I also have tried to change with all the activity name but still not working

Comment: what is problem now ?

Comment: I have find the solution for button where i need to put th clickLogin in activity that call the fragment.. But I am still stuck in recyclerview

Comment: @AmitVagela(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479347/android-how-to-pass-another-activity-application-context-from-java-class-exten)

Answer (score 1):

you are loading a layout xml which has a method **clickLogin()** probably for button.

Please check is there is a method with name **clickLogin()** in fragment.

Comment: Yes I have onclick attribute in xml..Do I need to delete that? So how to make the button work?

Comment: What should happen when u click that button?

Comment: Ok then.. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have assign clickLogin() method in your xml file for Button, on which you click, so just check your xml file you will find this in button tag as android:onclick="clickLogin"

So you need to declare this method in your class as below,

```
 public void clickLogin (View v)
 {   
 }
```

Comment: In which class should I add it?

Comment: where you have set your layout as this xml file or the activity or fragment where you can see this button and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define clickLogin() method in your fragment or simply setOnClickListener() for your button in the fragment.