# Android - How to pass another activity application context from java class extends fragments to asynctask?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Hi I am trying to make application that has view pager and tablayout. So when I choose 'friends' tab layout it will call java class named FragFriends.java,

In this class I want to inflate layout where recycler view adapter is filled with data from database that I retrieve using asynctask method in class PHPuserlist.java

However my application suddenly stopped

Here is the the FragFriends.java

```
public class FragmentFriends extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_view,container,false);// The activity that contains recyclerview
    View dview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile,container,false); //This is the activity that contains tablayout
    PHPUserList phpUserList = new PHPUserList(dview.getContext()); 
    phpUserList.execute();
    return rootview;
}

}
```

I have implement this recycler view with intent and it work just fine. But I need to use this with fragment
Pleas help me

This is the logcat

```
05-27 16:55:12.198 14031-14031/com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen, PID: 14031
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen.PHPUserList.onPreExecute(PHPUserList.java:82)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
        at com.rumahdosen.www.rumahdosen.FragmentFriends.onCreateView(FragmentFriends.java:20)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2332)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2252)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the PHPUserList.java

```
public class PHPUserList extends AsyncTask<Void,UserList,Void> {

private Context context;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
ArrayList<UserList> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

PHPUserList(Context ctx){

    this.context = ctx;
    activity = (Activity)ctx;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://njtwicomp.pe.hu/listuser.php");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");
        }

        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count = 0;
        while(count<jsonArray.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            count++;
            UserList userList = new UserList(JO.getString("Name"),JO.getString("Username"));
            publishProgress(userList);
        }
        Log.d("JSON STRING", json_string);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.RVUserList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(UserList... values) {
    arrayList.add(values[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
}
```

I try to find the recyclerview by id in another activity while I set the activity as the activity of the passed context. But I don't know how to fix that

So how do I get the activity which is not the context that I passed in asynctask?

Comment: getContext() is enough you dont need the view context.

Comment: did you solve this ?@NatJ

Comment: not yet @AmitVaghela

Comment: @k0sh I get red line for that

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
PHPUserList phpUserList = new PHPUserList(dview.getContext()); 
phpUserList.execute();
```

to :

```
new PHPUserList(getActivity()).execute();
```

Comment: If I use this function which activity context do I pass?

Comment: The activity which started the fragment

Comment: The application still crash though

Comment: Its seems the problem is in your PHPUserList class

Comment: I'll add the PHPUserList.java

Comment: I try to find the recyclerview by id in another activity while I set the activity as the activity of the passed context. But I don't know how to fix that

Comment: Your code is messed up, at first try to understand what you want to achieve for eg. you can set the adapter to the recyclerview in the fragment itself.

Comment: I am sorry but how to do that?

Comment: If the recycler view is in the activity layout, for what purpose are you using the fragment? What are you actually trying to achieve? And you cannot access recyclerview id that way

Comment: I have tab layout so I need fragment to inflate a layout right? I need a recycler view in that tab layout

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment class just put getActivity(), where Context is needed it will do the job!

Comment: Post the logcat, please!

Answer (score 0):

just use `getContext();`

This does the work.
In case you need to use the  Activity Context then Have static context of  `ClassName.this`